# How to save the exported file to the same path as the py file and rename my csv file to the folder name

Tags: python

I'm trying to scraping html files to csv files,and I want to  save the exported file to the same path as the py file and rename my csv file to the folder name. How to do it?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

directoryPath = r"./"
os.chdir(directoryPath)
folderLister = os.listdir(directoryPath)
for folders, sub_folders, file in os.walk(directoryPath):
    for name in file:
        if name.endswith(".html"):
            filename=os.path.join(folders,name)
            print(filename)
            print(name)
            dfs = pd.read_html(filename)
            html_filename = filename.replace('.html', '.csv')

            dfs[3].to_csv(html_filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

You check current path using this

```
import pathlib

current_path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from pathlib import Path  
FILE = Path(__file__) #give you the py file name
FILE.absolute() #give you the absolute path of the py file
FILE.parents[1].as_posix() #give you the folder name
```

Comment: How to use it  in my code?Sorry I haven't used pathlid before

Comment: Just import and use like other python libraries. Happy coding.